# Removed all undefined from a list of rules

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement, pattern-matching

My output from NSolve is a list of rules, most of these are undefined, I want to remove those rules.
More specifically I have a list

```
    rules = {y2 -> Undefined, y3 -> Undefined, y4 -> Undefined, y5 -> Undefined, 
 y6 -> Undefined, y7 -> Undefined, y8 -> Undefined, y9 -> Undefined, 
 y10 -> Undefined, y11 -> Undefined, \[Lambda]2 -> -1.68379, 
 y2 -> 0.991506, y3 -> Undefined, y4 -> Undefined, y5 -> Undefined, 
 y6 -> Undefined, y7 -> Undefined, y8 -> Undefined, y9 -> Undefined, 
 y10 -> Undefined, y11 -> 0.991506, \[Lambda]2 -> Undefined, 
 y2 -> Undefined, y3 -> 0.97847, y4 -> 0.969246, y5 -> 0.963328, 
 y6 -> 0.96037, y7 -> 0.96037, y8 -> 0.963328, y9 -> 0.969246, 
 y10 -> 0.97847, y11 -> Undefined, \[Lambda]2 -> Undefined}
```

and I want to get

```
{y2-> 0.991506, y3-> 0.969246,y4 -> 0.969246...}
```

and so on.
How do I remove all the undefined defitions, not that the final list doesnt have to be in this order.
`DeleteCases` and other functions didn't help.

Comment: `DeleteCases[_ -> Undefined]@rules`?

Comment: `Select[rules, FreeQ[#, Undefined] &]`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
t = rules /. HoldPattern[x_ -> Undefined] -> Nothing
```

**EDIT**

Another variation:

`Values[rules]` can be used: (Also try `Key[rules]` to get variable names)

```
pos = Position[Values[rules], Except[Undefined], {1}, Heads -> False]
```

> `{{11}, {12}, {21}, {24}, {25}, {26}, {27}, {28}, {29}, {30}, {31}}`

```
v = Extract[rules, pos]
```

---

result:

> `{\[Lambda]2->-1.68379,y2->0.991506,y11->0.991506,y3->0.97847,y4->0.969246,y5->0.963328,y6->0.96037,y7->0.96037,y8->0.963328,y9->0.969246,y10->0.97847}`

```
t == v   (* True *)
```

Comment: Or `rules/.(x_->Undefined):> Nothing` (a slight variant of your first method)

Comment: I have been learning good techniques for the last 24h. Many thanks to everyone who has participated so far.

Answer (score 10):

[`Select`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select.html) only [`NumericQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumericQ.html) solution

```
Select[rules, NumericQ[Last[#]]&]
```

Or delete the instances that include [`Undefined`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Undefined.html)

```
rules /.Rule[_,Undefined]->Nothing
```

Answer (score 8):

We can use [`DeleteCases`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteCases.html) as follows:

```
f1 = DeleteCases[_ -> Undefined]
(* Alternatively, f1 = DeleteCases[_ ~ _ ~ Undefined];*)

f1 @ rules
```

> ```
> {λ2 -> -1.68379, y2 -> 0.991506, y11 -> 0.991506, y3 -> 0.97847 , y4 -> 0.969246,
>  y5 -> 0.963328, y6 -> 0.96037, y7 -> 0.96037, y8->0.963328,
>  y9 -> 0.969246, y10 -> 0.97847}
> ```

Alternatives using operator forms of  [`Select`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select.html), [`Cases`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cases.html) and [`ReplaceAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html):

```
f2 = Select @* FreeQ @ Undefined;
f3 = Cases[_~ _ ~ Except @ Undefined];
f4 = ReplaceAll[_ ~ _ ~ Undefined -> Nothing];

f1 @ rules == f2 @ rules == f3 @rules == f4 @ rules
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Answer (score 4):

Using `SequenceSplit` (new in 11.3)

```
Catenate @ SequenceSplit[rules, {x_ /; ! NumericQ @ Last @ x}]
```

{λ2 -> -1.68379, y2 -> 0.991506, y11 -> 0.991506,
y3 -> 0.97847, y4 -> 0.969246, y5 -> 0.963328, y6 -> 0.96037,
y7 -> 0.96037, y8 -> 0.963328, y9 -> 0.969246, y10 -> 0.97847}

Using `Delete`

```
Delete[rules, Position[rules, _ -> Undefined]]
```

(* same result *)

Using `Extract`

```
Extract[rules, Position[rules, _ -> _?NumericQ]]
```

(* same result *)

Answer (score 3):

Using `Pick` and `NumericQ`:

```
Pick[#, NumericQ[#[[2]]] & /@ #] &@rules
```

> {λ2 -> -1.68379, y2 -> 0.991506, y11 -> 0.991506,
> y3 -> 0.97847, y4 -> 0.969246, y5 -> 0.963328, y6 -> 0.96037,
> y7 -> 0.96037, y8 -> 0.963328, y9 -> 0.969246, y10 -> 0.97847}